# My app published on Google play and antivirus says it's trojan

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play

My app got published on Google Play recently and I am happy about that. But when the app is installed on the phone the phone's antivirus detects trojans in it. I mean I don't even access any kind of permissions in my app but still.

Has anyone encountered this before?

These are the libraries I'm using:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx:20.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage-ktx:20.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx:21.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ktx:18.2.12'
def lottieVersion = "3.4.0"
implementation "com.airbnb.android:lottie:$lottieVersion"
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.8'
implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.4.0'
implementation files('/libs/unity-ads.aar')
```

Comment: It could potentially be related to one or more of the libraries you used in your app? The only way I can imagine checking for this as the issue is making another "app" which doesn't use any libraries, side load it onto your device, see if your antivirus still calls it a trojan. If not, add one or two of the libraries that you think might be triggering it, side load it, etc, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is maybe because google says: 'Hey the user is new and it can maybe be virus'

Or google says: 'Hey there are bad reviews or there arent any so maybe is a virus'

Comment: You maybe right but the admin app which is linked to the app on google play is also identified as trojan however the admin app is not even on google play. That's what making me more conserned.

Comment: @NoobProgrammer what is admin app?

Comment: the admin app is linked to the app published on google play so I can make changes if required.

Comment: @NoobProgrammer well Maybe you can wait day or two, app will maybe be reviewed and it will not be marked as trojan, otherwise you can try looking in code. I already have seen some games that Says: 'its trojan' but it was not.

Comment: yeah sure, I will give updates about the issue here if fixed.

Comment: hi! any news? I've exactly the same problem just updating the app.
the only thing I did was updating the OneSignal dependency the the 4.8.2 version, and update the comileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion to the 32 version

Answer (score 0):

in my case the problem was due to the OneSignal version 4.8.2, downgrading to 4.7.0 the problem disappeared.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Ohh. Yeah the library I used night be causing this issue. Thanks

Comment: OneSignal founder here, and I stumbled upon this thread from over a year ago. We've never heard of this from anyone else. If you still see any problems like this, please get in touch with us so we can troubleshoot and resolve the issue for you.

Answer (score 0):

It might be due to one of these libraries as i just got the same issue now so if you got these libraries with upgraded version inside your build.gradle file try toggling them back to these versions

implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.0'

This might solve the issue else try downgrading other implementions too to check which might be causing the issue